# Uploading Angular 2 app to web hosting

Tags: laravel, angular

So far I've used web hosting such as https://uk.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting for my websites, but seem like running angular 2 app has different way for publication.

So, since I found nothing about running Angular 2 app to be available public, and not only in localhost

My questions are -

1. What providers do allow such apps to be hosted on them? now I'm using `npm start` in my project folder to run my app, does it works the same way?
2. Since my backend is Laravel and supposed to be in the same domain as the Angular2 frontend, These providers allow to host the API's too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Copy your app files in the ```public``` folder of Laravel ?!

Comment: @BeS when using `npm start` the app works on port 3000, while laravel works on port 80, and its still localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also hosted my laravel backend and angular front end using openshift. In terms to your application, I recommend you the following two providers.

1. [Amazon Web Service](https://aws.amazon.com/).  You can get 1 year free trial, `EC2` is really wonderful to host whatever you want. In `EC2`, you can configure the environment for `angular 2` and `laravel` by yourself. You can run any command including `npm install` in `EC2`
2. [Openshift](https://openshift.redhat.com/). You can freely create 3 gears to host your application. The environment is very easy to configure. If you want
       to deploy `angular 2`, `laravel` applications, there are specific gears for these frameworks, so `openshift`
       should be the best choice.

The answer to your second question : Yes, they allow to host the APIs !

Comment: Thanks dude! You helped me alot! Do they support MySQL too? And why the prices are hourly rated? Isn't it about resources?

Comment: Yes, MySQL is supported. You can start a free trial firstly without caring about the price, so do I.

Comment: How did yo host angular2 with openshift?